# OTP generator in Visual Studio using Toolbox Feature

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOXQI.png)

I cant figure out this. Ive Used the toolBox feature for direct use of the components. I Want to understand how should i complete this.

(The image above is for the reference becuase i want it the same way)

Comment: You didn't provide any relevant information. Just a form with a button and a text box. You need to actually write code that generates the token when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you want to create actual TOTP tokens you need to use a library like [OTP.NET](https://github.com/kspearrin/Otp.NET)

Comment: im just confused with that part. I dont know how to start the code for generating otp.

Comment: Please try to ask a question like "Why does method A throw a NullReferenceException?" or "There are 2 methods OTP.New() and OTP.CreateNew(). Where's the difference?". Those are questions we can answer. "I don't know how to walk" is no question